# Report Viewer using multiple reports

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

Within vb.net we've got a report that works great it has it's header/footer details then then a table in the middle which repeats data and all of that is fine.

But what the client wants now is for another button named 'Print Individual' and this will print the same report but instead of the repeated data within the table for each of those rows to be a single row on a page with the same header/footer.

So for example on the first report if there is one page with 5 rows of details the 'Print Individual' report will print the same but have 5 pages and 1 row per report. If that makes sense :-)

Obviously if I can do it where we use the same report instead of maintaing two reports would be good, as the report has a lot of information on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new report and using the list box tool.